# Delphi - How build connection string to .mdb that changes directory location

Tags: delphi

Bit of a noob here. I am working on school practical in delphi. My project is saved on my one drive and each time I update the programe i create a new version, with a new directory. Example:

blah-blah\OneDrive\PAT(a folder containing all the files from the program including the .mdb)

inside this directory, which does not change, the final folder name, changes. Ex.:

blah-blah\OneDrive\PAT\V1

blah-blah\OneDrive\PAT\V2

blah-blah\OneDrive\PAT\V3 and so on...

My problem is that I am using a .mdb and everytime i copy the files to a new folder structure I have to go and build a new connection string to conntect to my database. I am using a simple ADO Connection.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thx in advance!

Comment: use git for source code version control.

Comment: So, with Git, would I be able to store all my version is a similar folder structure, and it would solve the connection string problem? Because as far as I know Git will just cause the same problem where my folders are stored on OneDrive.

Comment: You are correct about Git.  Using it will not solve the problem.

Comment: It depends how you will use source control (Git or any other) - with such source control you dont have to name different folder for each of your version.

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev:  True, but Git et al are irrelevant to the q the OP is asking, which id how to modify the connection string for the Mdb to match the path to the executable.  And using a UDL just moves the problem, it doesn't solve it.

Comment: @MartynA You are right about UDL, maybe I misunderstand his problem - I though the problem is that connection string is hard coded in source code and he doesnt want to change source code each time.

Comment: @Romans, sorry i misunderstood the problem. connectionstrting manipulation will solve your problem as MartynA explained.

Comment: Why not simple place the .mdb in the PAT folder and use a relative path in the connection string such as `..\mydb.mdb`? ( ..\ means one folder up from the current folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A connection string is just a string, so you can manipulate it in code just like any other string.  The expression `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` returns the path to your Exe's location, so all you need to is to set the path component of the Mdb file name to that.

One way to do this would be to define a string constant in your code for the
connection string value and put a placeholder in it for the path to the Mdb, like so

```
const
  scConnectionString = 'blahblahetc%pathtomdb%mymdb.mdbblahetc';
```

and then use the StringReplace function to substitute the correct path at run-time before you open the connection, as in

```
var
  APath : String;
[...]
  APath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  AdoConnection1.ConnectionString := StringReplace(scConnectionString, '%pathtomdb%', APath, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

ADO Connection string can be stored in UDL file, which is actually simple ini file. Then you have to change connection string in UDL file, not in your source code. [Universal Data Link (UDL) configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/help-topics/data-link-pages?view=sql-server-ver15)